# How do Xbox Rewards Credits convert to local currency cash?

Tags: xbox-network

Since dropping Microsoft Points as a currency, the Xbox Rewards program now racks up "Credits" that are converted into currency after reaching certain tiers like 5000. The [FAQ](http://rewards.xbox.com/faq/) says:

> **What happened to Microsoft Points?**
>
> A. Microsoft Points are officially retiring. Instead, you can use money to purchase content on Xbox (see Xbox.com Points FAQ) for more information). With this change, it became necessary for us to evolve the way we reward you. Instead of Microsoft Points, Xbox Live Rewards members can now earn Rewards Credits, which are converted into your local currency and deposited as cash directly into your Microsoft account.

I don't see a posted Credits conversion rate. Is it a fixed or variable rate? How does it differ between currencies? How can I predict the cash payout from my Credits?

Comment: I couldn't make heads or tails of this either.  It doesn't seem like they've fully converted over from MS points to cash in the Xbox Live profiles, either.

Comment: Credits are their tracking system, similar to their points system on the old rewards site. Think of it as separate currency. Another user has already posted a valid answer to the number of credits needed for a payout and the payout's value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I look on their [FAQ](http://rewards.xbox.com/faq/), I see:

> > Q. What is the monetary value of Rewards Credits?
> >
> > A. 5,000 Rewards Credits are equal to £3.35.

I would guess that if you look at it, while signed into your account, it will show you the value in your local currency.

Comment: Here in the US, that line reads `5,000 Rewards Credits are equal to $5 USD.`

Comment: So basically 1250 credits equal $1.25.

Comment: Its not a static answer, now 5,000 Rewards Credits are equal to £3.00.

Comment: Is that not reflected in the source linked?